# Avoiding a second gateway on an industrial machine WAN connection

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy

- I have an industrial machine. The vendor has added an industrial VPN box (device A below) and has set all the devices on the LAN to use it as the gateway.
- The vendor is extremely security conscious and will not set up (if possible) NAT rules to allow me to communicate with the devices on the machine LAN. This prevents me collecting machine data as well as giving remote support from the office or from home.

[image]

What is the correct terminology or name for device B that would feature,

- A WAN and LAN port.
- Ability to set multiple WAN addresses and tie or forward requests to these addresses to specific LAN addresses.
- Make the requests appear as local so that the response doesn't require the use of the gateway (which would send the response off in the wrong direction).

Is it a class of reverse proxy?
I presume that this problem has been solved many times before and that a Linux configuration could help. What search terms should I use?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have complete configuration control over both routers?

Comment: Either eliminate B or put it underneath A. I suggest eliminating it and ensuring A can do all you need. Just have one entry point to the internet and then you will just have one gateway. Keep it simple.

Comment: 'A' being a VPN Server presumably, what exactly prevents you from connecting to its VPN to access the machine LAN for "collecting machine data as well as giving remote support from the office or from home"?

Comment: @Ramhound, no. I have control over B but the vendor has control over A.

Comment: @John, that wouldn't work if A is firewalling inbound traffic and I need separate NAT forwarding rules for 1:1 WAN-LAN addresses.

Comment: @xenoson, the VPN device is locked to me and would also requires the VPN software to run on any of my devices trying to connect to the machine.

Comment: Except it sounds like these PLCs are connected to that VPN, which is the proper configuration, which means they won't be accessible to any device NOT connected to the VPN.  At least that is my assumption based on what I would do to secure the devices from the outside world.

Comment: So you cannot configure the VPN device. I would agree that avoiding to use the VPN from within your business LAN is not much of an security issue under most circumstances. But from outside (home) you should connect via VPN. If you cannot configure A adding the router B alone would not help on its own, because you need to set routes to the other LAN on every client in your machine LAN. Would be easier to configure A the proper way. No port forwards from the internet but access from your business LAN.

Comment: Put the VPN Gateway to the outside word and connect your LAN to a switch. If you need separation of subnets for business and machine use VLAN. That's how this is supposed to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** It really sounds a lot like a regular *router* (aka gateway). All features you've listed are the usual NAT (SNAT and DNAT) that routers are typically capable of.

For example, the 2nd item is regular DNAT (aka "port forwarding"), only with more specific match parameters – what you need is a router that allows matching on "external IP" in the DNAT rules, which many actually do. Similarly, the 3rd item is the same kind of SNAT (aka "masquerading") that many routers already do on the WAN interface, only in your case it's done exiting the LAN interface instead.

So the main thing to look for is whether the router's firmware is flexible enough, i.e. what you want is *not* the specific "home/office wireless" kind of router that assumes a fixed use case, but a more generic "enterprise router" that lets you build its behavior from scratch. (I don't know if that's actually the right term – it doesn't have to be enterprise-priced, of course – but really the problem is that it *is* just a generic router. Sometimes "enterprise firewall" might also fit.)

As a specific example, devices with RouterOS or OpenWRT should have the necessary capabilities. A computer with two Ethernet ports running an OS capable of routing and NAT (e.g. any Linux with nftables/iptables, or some BSD variant with *pf*) would also do the job fine.

**b)** That being said, everything could *also* be done with a "reverse proxy", the main difference is that proxies work at higher layers, e.g. instead of raw IP packets they deal with TCP connections or even individual HTTP requests, so you need to choose it based on what kind of communications you'll be performing.

But this actually means your 3rd feature is "built in" to all reverse proxies, as internally the proxy would establish a whole new connection from its own LAN address – instead, *preserving* the source address would be harder.

Reverse proxies also somewhat overlap with "load balancers" (many advertise themselves as both). They aren't necessarily dedicated devices or appliances, commonly they're just software running on a general computer such as Nginx, HAproxy, or relayd.

So if your requests are all HTTP-based, then an HTTP reverse proxy would work (it could even add HTTPS on the WAN side while still talking plaintext HTTP internally), but many proxies/balancers can do raw TCP as well. (I think generic UDP support is less common though, but not nonexistent.)

---

In both cases, I think "WAN and LAN ports" isn't really what you're looking for. I'd say quite the opposite – an enterprise router that *doesn't* have such ports pre-defined (and just has Ethernet1, Ethernet2, etc.) is more likely to be flexible enough for your purposes than a router which does.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed considerations. I think "masquerading" is the term I'm looking for! My traffic isn't just HTTP - it will include industrial protocols and VNC, etc. I think I need to avoid any kind of port forwarding for now.

Comment: @Transistor: "Ability to set multiple WAN addresses and tie or forward requests to these addresses to specific LAN addresses" *is* basically what people call "port-forwarding".

Comment: OK. I've only seen it used where a user has one Internet IP address so forwards inbound on port 80 to host1:80 and forwards inbound on port 81 to host2:80 (or that kind of setup). I'll dig deeper. I need individual WAN addresses mapped to individual LAN addresses.